# What does "dry" mean?

Tags: dc, the-suicide-squad-2021

In *The Suicide Squad* (2021), Rick Flag and his crew reached a shore by swimming:

> Rick Flag: Waller, we're on the beach and **dry**.

What does "dry" mean?

Comment: An interesting question. 'Dry' isn't particularly military slang used by infiltration teams.

Comment: The ocean is wet. Land is dry.

Comment: I haven't seen the film so I can't give this as an answer, but in everyday language "home and dry" would mean out of trouble/job done and everyone safe, so perhaps it's a play on that - they're not exactly home and dry yet, but they're getting there and have at least reached the beach. In this case, then, "dry" on its own doesn't really have much meaning outside of the larger phrase. Like I said. I haven't seen the film, so this is just a guess (and therefore a comment, not an answer).